Does the functor $- \otimes B : R^{Mod} \to (R \otimes S)^{Mod}$ have a right adjoint?
Let $R,S$ be unital rings. Fix an $S$ module $B$. Now consider the functor $F_B:R^{Mod} \to (R\otimes S)^{Mod}$ given by $F_B(A)=A\otimes B$. To be clear, the $R\otimes S$ module structure on $A\otimes B$ is given by $(r\otimes s).(a\otimes b)=r.a\otimes s.b$. I was wondering whether $F_B$ has a right adjoint $G_B:(R\otimes S)^{Mod} \to R^{Mod} $. So, we need $Hom_{(R\otimes S)^{Mod}}(A\otimes B, M) \simeq Hom_{R^{Mod}}(A, G_B(M))$.
I thought of the the following.We think of $M$ as an $R$-module: $r.m=(r\otimes 1).m$ and as an $S$ module: $s.m=(1\otimes s).m$. We now take $G_B(M)=Hom_{S^{Mod}}(B,M)$. The $R-Mod$ structure on $Hom_{S^{Mod}}(B,M)$ is obtained by $(r.f)(b)=(r\otimes 1).f(b)$ for $f \in Hom_{S^{Mod}}(B,M)$ and $b\in B$. I did not investigate this further, as I hope that someone more knowledgeable than me can immediately point out if there are any flaws here.
Note: All the modules considered here are left modules.

Over which ring do you take the tensor product? Just $\mathbb{Z}$?

This is correct. More generally, let $R,S$ be $k$-algebras, where $k$ is a commutative ring, and let $B$ be some $S$-module. We claim that $- \otimes_k B : R^{\mathrm{Mod}} \to (R \otimes_k S)^{\mathrm{Mod}}$ is left adjoint to $\hom_S(B,-)$.
We will use the well-known fact that for a $k$-module $M$ the functor $M \otimes_k -$ is right adjoint to $\hom_k(M,-)$. A $k$-linear map $f : M \otimes_k N \to T$ corresponds to a $k$-linear map $g : M \to \hom_k(N,T)$ via $g(m)(n) = f(m \otimes n)$.
Let $A$ be some $R$-module. Let $C$ be some $R \otimes_k S$-module. Then
$$\begin{align*}
& \quad ~  \hom_{R \otimes_k S}(A \otimes_k B, C)\\  & = \{f \in \hom_k(A \otimes_k B,C) : r \,f(a \otimes b) = f(ra \otimes b), ~ s \,f(a \otimes b) = f(a \otimes sb)\} \\
& \cong \{g \in \hom_k(A,\hom_k(B,C)) : r \, g(a)(b) = g(ra)(b), ~ s \, g(a)(b) = g(a)(s b)\} \\
& = \{g \in \hom_k(A,\hom_R(B,C)) : g \text{ is } R\text{-linear}, \, \text{each } g(a) \text{ is } S\text{-linear}\} \\
& = \hom_R(A,\hom_S(B,C)).
\end{align*}$$
It is now also clear that this argument is purely formal and holds in a very general setting. Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be any closed symmetric monoidal category. Let $R,S$ be two monoid objects in $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$. Let $B$ be some $S$-module object. Then $- \otimes B : \mathbf{Mod}_\mathcal{C}(R) \to \mathbf{Mod}_\mathcal{C}(R \otimes S)$ is left adjoint to a suitably defined functor $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_S(B,-)$.
